# Jquery Returning undefined when using "click" listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML:

```html
<div action="https://github.com/">
     <div class="menu-bar-item">
         <h1 class="menu-item-text">GitHub</h1>
     </div>
</div>
```

And JavaScript:

```js
$(document).on("click", "*[action]", (e) => {

    try {
        var attribute = $(e.target).attr("action");
        alert(attribute)

    } catch(e){}
})
```

Here attribute `action` is sometimes retuning "undefined". How do I fix?

Comment: Why not use standard a tags?

Comment: `action` is not a standard attribute on a `div` element, which may be causing your issue. Use a `data` attribute instead, eg `<div data-action="https://github.com/">` in your HTML, then `$(e.target).data("action");` in the JS

Answer (score 2):

Get the event's `currentTarget` instead, which returns the element the event listener has been attached to:

```js
$(document).on("click", "*[action]", (e) => {
  try {
    var attribute = $(e.currentTarget).attr("action");
    alert(attribute)
  } catch (e) {}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div action="https://github.com/">
     <div class="menu-bar-item">
         <h1 class="menu-item-text">GitHub</h1>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still not working for me

Comment: @HarryTom Can you provide some HTML which won't work? It works with the HTML you provided.